# Microsoft Blend June 2.5 expired

Tags: wpf, xaml

I can't find newer Microsoft Blend Preview. Is it available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Replaced by SP1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/25/silverlight-2-release-candidate-now-available.aspx):

> “Rather than give it a new version
>   string (and force existing users to
>   upgrade to a new version), we decided
>   to release the functionality using a
>   service pack for the existing shipping
>   product. All the functionality that
>   was in previous Blend 2.5 builds is
>   now included in SP1.”

Answer (score 6):

I read in another forum a while ago, that 2.5 was replaced by Blend 2 with SP1.

Edit:
I found it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/FAQ.aspx?key=blend):

> Q. What happened to Expression Blend 2.5?
>
> A. Expression Blend 2.5 provided support
>   for Silverlight 2 through its Beta
>   cycle, both Beta 1 and Beta 2.
>   Silverlight 2 has now been released
>   and the Silverlight 2 platform support
>   that Expression Blend 2.5 enabled is
>   being made available to all our
>   Expression Blend users via the
>   Expression Blend 2 Service Pack 1.

Comment: Actually, since this is the official (FAQ) answer, I'd argue this is the better reply and deserves the tick. I've given it +1, anyway ;-p

Answer (score 0):

Installing SP1 extends the trial with 60 days